# Scroll position on initial page load does not go to hash/anchor position when directly accessed the URL in nuxt app

Tags: javascript, nuxt.js

I have a few anchor links in my nuxt.js app. It works fine.
Say, When I try to access the part of the page via navbar/ tag with id attribute it works fine.

`<a href="#anchor">Scroll to anchor</a>` - This works
`<nuxt-link to="#anchor">Scroll to anchor</a>` - also works

But when I try to access the same directly via URL like - `xxx.com/test#anchor` It takes to the test page but doesn't scroll to #anchor div.

Few workarounds I've tried are,

```
<nuxt-link :to="{path: '/', hash: 'anchor'}">link</nuxt-link>
```

I have changed the scroll behaviour supporting this in nuxt-config as well,

```
scrollBehavior(to, from, savedPosition) {
    if (to.hash) {
      return {
        selector: to.hash
      }
    } else {
      return {
        x: 0,
        y: 0
      }
    }
  },
```

This didn't work on load. I've found the same kind of issue has been raised but still open,

https://github.com/nuxt/nuxt.js/pull/6922

https://github.com/nuxt/nuxt.js/issues/6921

Comment: The nuxt version I am using is 2.11.0

Answer (score 0):

Had a similar issue and this hack resolved it.

```js
  mounted() {
    if (this.$route.hash) {
      let hash = this.$route.hash
      hash = hash.replace('#', '')
      const anchor = document.getElementById(hash)

      if (anchor) {
        window.scrollTo({
          top: anchor.getBoundingClientRect().top + window.scrollY,
        })
      }
    }
  },
```